# Articles in brackets

Tags: grammar, articles

My task was to design and implement the ***the/a*** company "laboratory" model (***the/a*** small social network for shop customers).

I am confused about using articles on the top sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My task was to design and implement *the* company laboratory model (*the* small social network for shop customers)

The definite articles because you are talking about *one and only* specific model or project you were working on. Furthermore, you are *redefining* the same - what is that company laboratory model.